# Reloading closed jupyter notebook

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter

Was trying to run the code in jupyter which runs fine:

```
import time

for i in range(10000):
     print(i)
     time.sleep(1)
```

After it prints to around 1,2,3,4,5,6 , I decided to close the browser.
However when I reopened the browser, the output is still stuck at 6. I was wondering if there's a way to keep the kernel running and update the output when the notebook is reloaded in the browser after it is closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no way to restore it.
Kernel is still running, but the browser will not update itself.

Comment: I see.... can i clarify that the kernel is still running the code once it is done with the running it will display the whole output back to the browser? or there's no way of getting the print to print out to the browser once you have closed it

Comment: yup as per https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/4138 seems like it can't be done.